# Stripe shows no such token: tok_xxxxxxx for destination charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a destination charge from my customer to one of the connected account.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY); //Origin Stripe Secret Key

        try {
            $connectd_account_id = 'acct_XXXXXXX';
            $customer_id = 'cus_XXXXXXX'
            // sharing my customer with connected account and creating a token. 
            $token = \Stripe\Token::create(
                                    ["customer" => $customer_id], //doctor stripe customer id
                                    ["stripe_account" => $connectd_account_id]); //Lab Stripe Account

            // I am receiving response ** No such token: tok_xxxxxxx **
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                                                "amount" => 10000,
                                                "currency" => 'USD',
                                                "source" => $token->id,
                                                "application_fee_amount" => 2000,
                                                "transfer_data" => [
                                                    "destination" => $connectd_account_id,
                                                ],
                                            )
                                        );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
```

everytime I receive 
**No such token: tok_xxxxxxx**
What's my mistake here I can't locate. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a destination charge, the card token and customer and related objects should all be created on your platform account. Your platform account is the one interacting with the cardholder and processing the payment, there is then just a transfer of funds within Stripe to the destination account.

Your code appears to be attempting to [clone saved card details](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods) from your platform to the destination account, which is *not* what you would do for a Destination charge(you'd only do this if you were using Direct charges where the payment is processed on the connected account and thus need to copy payment information there).

In short, you should omit the code for creating a token, and instead when creating the charge, pass something like `"source" => $customer_id,` to charge the customer details on your platform.

Comment: you are correct, the only thing is, instead of `source` , `customer` key should be used. `"customer" => $customer_id`